# python 2.6 - django TestCase - assertRaises ValidationError clean() method

Tags: python, django, python-2.6, testcase

Django 1.5 and Python 2.6.

The model has a `clean()` method that validates that `job.company_id` must equal `job.location.company_id`

I'm trying to write a test for this, but instead of passing/failing the test, the test is ending with the validation error message from the model's `clean()` method.

Here's the code (irrelevant bits omitted):

In models.py:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Job title")
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)    
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, blank=True, null=True)

    def clean(self):
        from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
        '''
        Location.company_id must equal Job.company_id
        '''
        if (self.company_id != Location.objects.get(pk=self.location_id).company_id):
            raise ValidationError('Location is not valid for company')
```

In tests.py:

```
class job_cannot_have_invalid_location_and_can_have_valid_location(TestCase):
    def test_jobs_and_locations(self):
        job2 = Job.objects.create(company_id=company2.id)
        location1 = Location.objects.create(company_id=company1.id)
        job2.location_id = location1.id
        self.assertRaises(ValidationError, job2.clean())
```

When I run python manage.py test:

```
.E.
======================================================================
ERROR: test_jobs_and_locations     (companies.tests.job_cannot_have_invalid_location_and_can_have_valid_location)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/djangobox/jobboard/companies/tests.py", line 60, in test_jobs_and_locations
    self.assertRaises(ValidationError, job2.clean())
  File "/home/djangobox/jobboard/companies/models.py", line 151, in clean
    raise ValidationError('Location is not valid for company')
ValidationError: [u'Location is not valid for company']
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is your usage of `assertRaises`. It should take the exception and the callable to check: http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises

However, you aren't passing the callable `job2.clean` you are passing the return value of the callable `job2.clean()`. Changing the call to

```
self.assertRaises(ValidationError, job2.clean)
```

should fix the exception and your test case.